# MySQLi Error Handling?

Tags: php, architecture, mysqli

I started using OO-MySQLi after procedural MySQL and I have a problem.

In production environment my system displays all errors as a custom page.
MySQLi errors is an "error" too and I want catch them, but in documentation described only one way to do this:

```
if (!$mysqli->query("SET a=1")) {
    exit('An error occurred: ' . $mysqli->error);
}
```

(just for example).
This is a very bad way, because in my system I'm doing many things when error occurred, like logging, calling events, etc.

Of course, I can extend mysqli class, for example:

```
class myMysqli {
    public function __construct(/* ... */)
    {
        parent::__construct(/* ... */);
    }

    public function query(/* .. */)
    {
        parent::query(/* ... */);

        if($this->errno !== 0)
        {
            // An error occurred
        }
    }
}
$mysqli = new myMysqli(/* ... */);
$mysqli->query(/* ... */);
```

But this way I need to extend almost **ALL** methods where error can occur.
Moreover, MySQLi provides prepared statements (mysqli_stmt class) that has its own errors!

Can you know a better way to handle MySQLi errors?
Thank you in advance.

---

**Added**

About exceptions:
Do I understand correctly that with exceptions I need do something like this:

```
try {
    $mysqli->query(/* ... */);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // An error occurred
}
```

But this is similar to

```
if(!$mysqli->query(/* ... */))
{
    // An error occured
}
```

What a difference?

Comment: Look into [exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: Or just write a method that logs the error and shows a user friendly message, and call that method when an error occurs.

Comment: @JohnConde yes, I can, but this way I need to surrond any MySQLi call with if/else block...

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php and the const FLAG for `MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **your old approach was wrong.**

```
exit('An error occurred: ' . $mysqli->error);
```

is a bad practice in general and shouldn't be used with mysqli as well.

What you really want is error/exception **handler**. Where you can do whatever things like logging, calling events, showing pages.

Exception is better than regular error - so, set your mysqli in exception mode as shown in other answer, and then catch all the errors in error handler. While try..catch have to be used **only** when you have a distinct particular action to handle the error.

Comment: I know it's a bad practice, I wrote, "just for example".
I decided to use PDO instead of MySQLi and I use it with exceptions.
Anyway, thank you for your answer even after 10 months, Merry Christmas!

Answer (score -1):

I use the try...catch method like this...

```
try {
    // get result of record from 'id'
    $query = "SELECT * FROM models WHERE id =$id";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    if (!$result) {
        throw new Exception($mysqli->error());      
    } 
    $row = $result->fetch_array(); 
 }
 catch (Exception $e)  
 {
     echo "We are currently experiencing issues. Please try again later.";
     echo $e->getMessage();
 } 
 finally
 {
      $result->free();
 }
```

Does that help at all?

You use 'try' to test a condition and throw an exception if it returns true (!$result). And use 'catch' to catch everything else that might just happen!